# CNN where pixels are constituted by large, potentially sparse vectors

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, sparse

I'd like to apply a CNN to a problem where the image is essentially a matrix representation of a geographical map where matrix indices correspond to the locations of buildings and roads.  Each location will have various features associated with it which would be represented by a sparse vector corresponding to a pixel.  The reason I am applying a CNN to this dataset is that I think shape data is important to phenomenon I am trying to learn, however, I've only ever encountered vectorized pixels in the context of representing rgb values for colorized images.

My questions are:
1) Is this a sensible approach to the type of data I am trying to learn from?  Are CNNs a good fit or are there better options?

2) Are there any good examples of this sort of semi-pictoral approach working?  Are there existing applications of CNNs where each training datum consists of a matrix of spatially arranged locations associated with a set of non-pictoral information, such as location-type (park, road, building, etc.)?

Comment: In principle there's no reason why CNN's wouldn't work on such a dataset. If anything they will run really fast especially if the convolutions take advantage of sparsity. See for example this paper, where the objective is to create sparse kernels (which your problem will presumably have): http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liu_Sparse_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a sensible approach.

I have a friend who researches search using deep networks, and this is part of what they do. Their [lab](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bulitko/research/rths/index.html) has a few papers, such as this one on [per-map algorithm selection](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~bulitko/research/rths/publications/2016-AIIDE.pdf):

> We attempted to select the best algorithm for a problem
>   by finding problems with similar start and goal states on the
>   same map and then combining the algorithms found to perform
>   well on them. The results were worse than the those
>   of the “prior” method likely due to the poor octile-distancebased
>   similarity metric (e.g., close-by start states separated
>   by a wall would be considered similar). Future work will
>   investigate better similarity metrics.
>
> We also represented a problem as a bitmap image of the
>   video-game map with the start and goal states shown on
>   it in color. We then trained deep convolutional networks
>   AlexNet and GoogleNet as included in MatConvNet framework
>   (Vedaldi and Lenc 2015) to predict the six parameters
>   of a suitable algorithm for it. The results were slightly
>   worse than those of the “prior” method. We are currently
>   investigating using convolutional deep networks to predict
>   algorithm suboptimality on a given problem, represented by
>   a bitmap image.